# How to set encoding when stream blob from Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an `XML` file in my blob storage. It contains words like this: `Družstevní`.
When I download the `XML` using Azure portal, this word is still correct.
But when I try using `DownloadToStreamAsync` the result is `Dru�stevn�`.

How do I fix this?

I found `DownloadTextAsync` is working because I get set the encoding: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`.
But then I end up with a string and the rest of my code is expecting a stream.     Should I read the string again as a stream or exists a more elegant option?

Here's my code:

```
public Task<string> DownloadAsTextAsync(string code, Encoding encoding)
{
    var blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(code);
    var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
    {
        MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
        ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
    };

    return blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), null, blobRequestOptions, null);
}

public async Task<Stream> DownloadAsStreamAsync(string code)
{
    var blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(code);
    var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
        {
            MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
        };
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(output, null, blobRequestOptions, null);
    return output;
}
```

**Edit**, after comment of Zhaoxing Lu:
I changed my unit test and added the encoding to StreamReader and now the unit test is passing:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.StartsWith("            <Str>Dru")) continue;

        Debug.WriteLine(line);
        var street = line.Trim().Replace("<Str>", "").Replace("</Str>", "");
        Assert.AreEqual("Družstevní", street);
    }
}
```

But in my 'real' code I'm sending the stream to load as `XML`:

```
fileStream.Position = 0;
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(fileStream);
```

The resulting `xmlDocument` is in the wrong encoding. I can't find how to set the encoding.

Comment: Could you share the code how you consume `Stream` returned from `DownloadAsStreamAsync`? I think this is the place you need to change. `Stream` is just a binary stream, it's the reader who can decide the encoding when consuming the stream.

Comment: Thanks @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft I've updated my post and you are right the stream is OK. The problem seems to be when reading the stream as an `XDocument`

Comment: Glad to hear that the stream is good. Regarding the XDocument issue, I'd suggest you to create a new question since the question above was about Azure Blob Storage topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem seems to be when reading the stream as an XDocument

You could set the encoding as `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` with the following code to read the stream as XDocument.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = null;

using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))
{
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(oReader);
}
```

The result:
[image]